# List appends dictionary before it is asked to do so

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to append dictionaries to a list, that is, I need a list of dictionaries for further processing.
The information comes from email messages so I'm using the 'ezgmail' module.

What happens is an unexpected behaviour in the aforementioned list, where it seems to update before I ask it to do so. Let's start with an example so I can make myself better understood.

If I do:

```py
listdict = []
dictname = {'name':'John'}
listdict.append(dictname)
dictname = {'name':'Sarah'}
listdict.append(dictname)
print(listdict)
[{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Sarah'}]
```

Which is totally normal and the expected result. But this is what happens to me in my real case:

```py
### Here I search for unread emails with ezgmail.search, then get the amount of unread messages with the same subject, and verify whether there are unread messages or not and how many there are, then:
###
orderDict = {}
orderList = []
for number in range(amountMessages):
  message = orderEmails[0].messages[number] # fetches the specific message as a message object
  stringMessage = str(message)  # converts message object to string, needed for re.findall
  stringName = re.search("(Name: )+(\w+\s\w+)", stringMessage) # finds Name: xxx and separates both parts 
  creating a tuple inside a list
  name = stringName.group(2)
  orderDict['Name'] = name
  stringEmail = re.findall("([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}))", stringMessage) # 
  finds email addresses
  tempEmailtuple = stringEmail[2] # it is always email #3 what we need
  email = tempEmailtuple[0]  # the first part of the tuple contains the whole email address
  orderDict['Email'] = email
  orderList.append(orderDict)
```

When I did this, I observed that only the last message's info is appended. Thinking that I'm a newbie and likely screwed something up I decided to do everything manually in the Python console instead of using the for loop, just with the 'name' key in the dictionary.

```py
message = orderEmails[0].messages[0]
stringMessage = str(message)
stringName = re.search("(Name: )+(\w+\s\w+)", stringMessage)
name = stringName.group(2)
orderDict['Name'] = name
orderList.append(orderDict)

#so far so good, but

message = orderEmails[0].messages[1]
stringMessage = str(message)
stringName = re.search("(Name: )+(\w+\s\w+)", stringMessage)
orderDict['Name'] = name
```

And this is where the magic happens. When using `PyCharm`, I can clearly see that at this exact moment `orderList` is updated with the current `value` in `orderDict['name']`. How is that possible, if I haven't even called `orderList` yet?

Comment: Please declare the dictionary inside the loop:

Comment: You're appending the same dictionary every time, not creating a new dictionary.

Comment: Thank you all. The orderDict outside the loop was a remnant of other approaches I had tried and it just slipped. My question still remains though, on why does orderList change at the same time orderDict changes. That's the part I really don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When, in your code, you have:

```py
orderDict = {}

for number in range(amountMessages):
    ...
    orderDict['Email'] = email
```

You are updating the same `dict` each time.

What you should have is this:

```py
for number in range(amountMessages):
    orderDict = {}
    ...
    orderDict['Email'] = email
```

Here you create `orderDict` anew each time through the loop.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the clarification. Now what I still don't understand is why doing it the way I did orderList keep changing whenever orderDict changes, even though it hasn't yet reached the orderList.append(orderDict) line yet. Sorry if this seems obvious, but could you clarify this a bit further?

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Thank you, that link was insightful.